# Flexslider z-index fails navigation

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, flexslider

I have Flexslider working nicely. However, I needed it to slide under a navigation bar so set it's margin-top to -75px and it's div.flexslider z-index to -2. Looks great but now the next/prev arrows don't fly in and the click navigation doesn't work. It's just an automatic slide show right now.  If I remove the z-index setting, it works but shows over the top of the nav bar.

It's sitting in a site using bootstrap 3 :-

```
    <div class="row">            
            <div class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                  <img src="images/garden.jpg" />
                </li>                      
                <li>
                  <img src="images/house.jpg" />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>               
    </div>
```

In Chrome there are no errors thrown in the dev tools. In Firefox, the slider disappears altogether unless the browser window is reduced in size.

What else do I need to adjust to allow the prev/next and slide navigation to work with the z-index set or is there another way?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for us to play with?

Comment: Never done one, but can have a go.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how this works.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/craig100/cmym73uk/ (Line 95 in the CSS)

Comment: Looks like setting the `.flexslider` to `z-index: -2` is pushing it below the default value, causing strange stuff like the dots to disappear. I'd recommend pulling the important stuff up rather than pushing stuff down. If I'm not mistaken, the `.container` sits at `z-index: 0`

Comment: Yes, I'd tried that but couldn't get it to work, hence calling out on here. Might have to swap out the slider for another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be removing the z-index:-2 on the flexslider. Then to push the nav over the top of it, had to add position:relative AND z-index:10. So the position:relative was the key to the solution.

Hope this helps someone else.

Craig